# Question on hold not notified

Tags: support, tags, on-hold

One of my [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1389722/download-size-count-switching-from-kib-to-mib-only-after-2mib) was put [on-hold](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/on-hold), yet I wasn't notified. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: As far as I understand, yes. I'll look through main meta for the reasoning later, since this is a network level thing.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be on hold any more. A temporary blip?

Comment: @Burgi, no the question was put on hold by DavidPostill but was released later. This question though is a generic one, I feel the user should be notified. JourneymanGeek says it is intentional.

Comment: This question seems to have had been answered by JeffAtwood according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-is-put-on-hold), but the answer was deleted for some reason.